# "Warning: Unexpected character in input" on server but not on localhost

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The stripe script below works fine on my localhost using XAMP, but when I uploaded it to my hosted server I got the following error.

**How can I fix it and why didn't it show on my localhost?**

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /storage/content/09/domain.com/public_html/test/pay.php on line 34

Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /storage/content/09/domain.com/public_html/test/pay.php on line 34

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /storage/content/09/domain.com/public_html/test/pay.php on line 34
```

Line 34 (error is on every \Stripe-line

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
```

Stripe script:

```
try {
        $stripePaymentData = $tool->getStripePaymentDataFromOrder($order);

        if($stripePaymentData['status']==1){

            require_once('vendors/stripe-php-2.1.1/config.php');

            $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
            $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'card'  => $token
            ));

            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'amount'   => $stripePaymentData['amount'],
            'currency' => $stripePaymentData['currency']
            ));

            $showDone = true;
            $stripeDone = true;
        }else{
            $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
        }
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
      $body = $e->getJsonBody();
      $err  = $body['error'];
      $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
/*
      print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
      print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
      print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
      // param is '' in this case
      print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
      print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
*/
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
        $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
        $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
        $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
        $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $tool->message[] = 'Payment denied, your card will not be charged. Please try again.';
    }
```

Comment: Which line is line 34

Comment: @Bankzilla $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(

Comment: What are php versions on both machines? It's likely your host is php < 5.3

Comment: Looks like the server is running an ancient version of PHP. You can't do much other than upgrade.